# Why should I use ggraph() with set.seed() in R?

Tags: r, text-mining, ggraph

I've recently been learning text mining with `tidytext`.
Today, I encountered the following:

```
set.seed(2017)
ggraph(bigram_graph, layout="fr") + geom_edge_link() + geom_node_point() + 
geom_node_text(aes(label=name), vjust=1, hjust=1)
```

I've used the `set.seed()` function with other functions like `sample()`. But here, I don't understand why `ggraph` should be used with `set.seed()`.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: I believe in (the default layout of) a graph (i.e. how nodes are placed on the plot) is random; so setting a fixed seed ensures that graphs are identical. It's easy to check: Remove the `set.seed(2017)` statement and see if `ggraph(...) + ...` produces the same output when re-running multiple times.

Comment: Ahhhh! Thank you so much!

Comment: @MauritsEvers Could you please make your comment an answer? That's what it actually is, and as far as I can tell, it is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use a set.seed function because the results vary when performing a random performance. Figuratively speaking, imagine planting seeds. You can sow seeds anywhere in the land. The first seed planted and the second seed planted produce clearly different results. This is because the shape of the stem and the leaf are different. If you use the set.seed function, you will get the same results.